# $_GET does not work and query the property

Tags: php

I have a problem with $_GET method. I have retrieved some data about admins of a webpage from database & I added a hyperlink for users to get the information about that them.

Here's the code in my 1st page:

```
<?php if(($adminlevel)==1){
echo '
<h4 class="widgettitle">List of admins</h4>
<table class="table responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Admin Level</th>
</tr>
</thead>
'; getAdmins(); echo ' 
</table>
';
}else{
echo '<h4 class="widgettitle">You dont have permission to see this table</h4>';
}
?>         
<div class="divider15"></div>
```

The function **getAdmins()** goes like this:

```
    <?php 
function getAdmins(){
    global $con;
    $get_admin = "select * from admins order by id";
    $run_admin = mysqli_query($con,$get_admin);
    while($row_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($run_admin)){
        $id_admin = $row_admin['id'];

        echo "

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Trident</td>
                            <td class='center'><a href='editlevel.php?id=$id_admin' title='Clik to change admin level' target='_blank'>$adminlevel_admin</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

        ";
    }
}
?>
```

As you see I link the users from my first page to another page which is called **editlevel.php** by the function **getAdmins()**.

Therefore I made my hyperlink like this:

```
<a href='editlevel.php?id=$id_admin'>$adminlevel_admin</a>
```

And Here's the **editlevel.php** page:

```
    <body>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id_admin'])){
    $result_id = $_GET['id_admin'];
    $get_result = "select * from admins where id='$result_id'";
                            $run_result = mysqli_query($con,$get_result);
                            while($row_result= mysqli_fetch_array($run_result)){

                                $id_target = $row_result['id'];
                                $username_target = $row_result['username'];
                                $adminlevel_target = $row_result['adminlevel'];
                                $email_target = $row_result['email'];

                                echo '
<div class="mainwrapper">

   <div class="header">
        '; include "php/php_includes/overall/header.inc.php"; echo'
    </div>

    <div class="leftpanel">

        ';include "php/php_includes/overall/leftpanel.inc.php"; echo '

    </div><!-- leftpanel -->

    <div class="rightpanel">

        '; include "php/php_includes/gadgets/rightpanel.editlevel.php"; echo '

    </div><!--rightpanel-->

</div><!--mainwrapper-->
';
                            }
}
?>
</body>
```

So basically I used `if (isset($_GET['id_admin'])){` to get the results of the item which user clicked & try to retrieve the data of that item from database via that.. But the problem is nothing appears at my screen. No error message & no result. Please if you know how can I solve it please let me know!

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your link is:

```
<a href='editlevel.php?id=$id_admin'>$adminlevel_admin</a>
```

When it should be:

```
<a href='editlevel.php?id_admin=$id_admin'>$adminlevel_admin</a>
```

In order for it to work with:

```
if (isset($_GET['id_admin'])){
    $result_id = $_GET['id_admin'];
```

Edit: It goes without saying, you should never trust user input (such as `$_GET`). These values should be validated and sanitised before being used in SQL queries.

Comment: Oh my gosh! You did it man .. thanks alot ... I had this problem for along time!